# passing variables from code behind doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, variables, code-behind

I am successfully able to pass variables from code behind to javascript in IE, but not in firefox. 
What I do is I have these public variables in my code behind:
public string passedVar = "";
and it gets assigned to a value in the page load event:
passedVar = "In code behind";

and then in the aspx page, inside a script block, I do this:
var clientVar = "<%= passedVar %>";

and then I am able to access it in other js files of that page just fine... in IE only!

If I am using javascript; however, that variable in the .js is showing up as "undefined"

I can find alternate values like hiddenfield, but I want to know why this is not working like it should!

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to process data through Javascript, do an ajax call (sync or async) to an empty .aspx page (I mean code-behind only), get the data result on success event and process the data in the callback function.
Some code based on [JQuery samples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://myDomain/myPage.aspx",
  data: "par1=val1&par2=val2",
  async: false,
  success: function( data ) {
       /*
        * data contains the myPage.aspx response
        * it could be a single value or a comma-separated list of values
        * initialize passedVar or whatever
        */
});
```